# Prevent fastlane scan from hiding the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

Ever since some recent update of fastlane it prevents simulators from opening a visible window. Keyboard button taps are still audible and the UI tests are executed, but the simulator window itself is not opened.

This is ok in most cases, however right now I need to dig deep and see what's happening, as somehow fastlane executes the tests slightly different than Xcode, resulting in our CI server to go nuts. (Xcode = all tests run smoothly. fastlane = all UI tests fail, both locally and on the CI server.)

So: is there a way, some parameter or environment variable, to tell scan to open that window to be able to see what's happening?

(Yes I could use snapshot to generate screenshots at specific points, but it's simply not enough when wanting to find out what the hell is going on.)

Hope someone can help :)

**Found the solution:**

`scan` should use the simulator that is already open, however I got error messages when running `scan` when a simulator was running. Updating to `2.68.0` did the trick for me.

Comment: if it works in Xcode then this might be some missing settings, did you try setting `open_report` to `true` you can check more about it here [docs fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/scan/)

Comment: The report only states that the UI tests have failed and which assert was the cause. It doesn't give me any more information :/

Comment: Also: If I tell fastlane to gather the simulator logs as well, they are completely empty. So no clue there..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, snapshot and scan have no builtin option for this. As a workaround, you can launch the simulator by hand (right click on the Xcode icon in the Dock, `Open Developer Tool > Simulator`).

snapshot will close the simulator if it is open when run and print the following line:

```
Patching simulators '/Users/<home>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist' to scale to 100%
```

After that, it is safe to relaunch the simulator. For scan you can just keep the simulator running.

When snapshot or scan boot the simulators that you have configured and the simulator app is running, the windows will show up and you'll be able to see what is happening - but be careful as snapshot is run concurrently now, and this will open windows for **all** configured devices.

You can modify your configuration to only run on a single device while testing this way, or you can run a one-off action by running snapshot from the terminal like this:

```
fastlane run snapshot devices:"iPhone 6" languages:"de-DE" #... all other parameters are similarly supported
```

Comment: My question was about scan.. so is it possible to use your suggested workaround with scan as well?

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I just saw "UI Tests" and my mind immediately said "snapshot". To answer your question: scan does not do any patching, so simply launching the Simulator before running scan is enough to see what is happening on screen

Comment: Hmm interesting. This only works if I run `fastlane scan` from the command line and not my `fastlane test` lane. (My test lane does nothing else than start scan with the correct set of parameters.) When I use my `test` lane I get the following error: Malformed version number string com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-11-1 This has been the case since a recent update, hence my SO question. This error message only goes away if I close the simulator and *then* run `fastlane test`...

Comment: Interesting, can you file an issue on GitHub? In that case this seems like a bug, because in my test setup I was able to do exactly what you describe. But you should still be able to run your test lane and then launch the simulator to debug, for now

Comment: Mention @milch somewhere in the post body so that I'm notified there, then I'll take a look. Make sure to also follow all the instructions in the issue template please

Comment: Huh, apparently `2.67.0` or `2.68.0` fixed this behavior. I updated fastlane again and now it works like it should. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No problem. I've edited my answer to reflect that it is applicable to scan as well. Can you accept it to show that this solved your problem, in case others find this via search?